# How can I improve this random promo code generator script?

Tags: php

I have this script that generates random promo codes.

```
    }
    $length = 10;
    $characters = '123456789ABCDEFGHJKMNPQRSTUVWXYZ';
    $charactersLength = strlen($characters);
    $event = $request->event;
    $prefix = $request->prefix;
    $quantity = $request->quantity;
    $randomString = '';
    for ($x = 0; $x <= $quantity; $x++) {
        for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
            $randomString .= $characters[rand(0, $charactersLength - 1)];
        }

        $pin = "$prefix"."$randomString";
        $exists = Pin::where('pin', $pin)->first();
        if(!$exists){
            $new['pin'] = $pin;
            $new['event'] = $event;
            $new['user'] = '';
            Pin::create($new);
        }

        $randomString = '';
    }
```

It works but needs to be optimized as it can take forever to execute when the $quantity gets above a couple thousand.

I suspect the time hog is the bit that is looking if the pin exists.  I am sure there must be a more efficient way to ensure the random strings are unique.

Thoughts?  Thanks!

****** As pointed out random hash generation has been addressed here ******

Perhaps a part 2 to this question then...

Client has requested a set selection of chars for the random codes - '123456789ABCDEFGHJKMNPQRSTUVWXYZ'.  Is there a way to limit the chars output by md5 hash?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out John.  I did read that question.  I didn't think it was a dupe given that I was trying to bulk generate vs. create ad hock like the example.  However, now I am rethinking the entire approach.

Answer (score 0):

A much simpler way:

```
$randomString = sha1(rand(0, 2000));
```

Comment: How does this ensure what is generated is unique to the current set?

Comment: You could check it thought a database with confirm codes and delete them when they are confirmed. If it exitsts, regenerate one.

Comment: Fair. To be clear. My script needs to generate codes in bulk.  Not one off.  So I need to generate and insert 15k at a time.  Although, I guess now that I think about it, I could rethink the whole process and generate them as needed not in advance...